# Reading/writing a bmp file

Tags: c, file, fwrite, fread, bmp

I wrote a code to simply read/write (copy) a *.bmp file. But something is wrong my program runs over and over and over again ... I mean it looks like there is a while(true) loop inside or something. Heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct Pix
{
  unsigned char R;
  unsigned char G;
  unsigned char B;
  unsigned char L;
  int BW;
}Pix;
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct BitMap
{
    short Signature;
    long Reserved1;
    long Reserved2;
    long DataOffSet;

    long Size;
    long Width;
    long Height;
    short Planes;
    short BitsPerPixel;
    long Compression;
    long SizeImage;
    long XPixelsPreMeter;
    long YPixelsPreMeter;
    long ColorsUsed;
    long ColorsImportant;
    struct Pix *pixels
}BitMap;
#pragma pack(pop)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

unsigned long int i=0;//to count pixels readed
unsigned long int S=0;//number of pixcels to read

struct BitMap source_info;//to store bitmap info header
struct Pix source_pix;// to store pixcels

FILE *fp;//file pointer for source file
FILE *Dfp;//file ponter for distenation file

if(!(fp=fopen("in.bmp","rb")))//open in binery read mode
{
printf(" can not open file");//prind and exit if file open error
exit(-1);
}


Dfp=fopen("out.bmp","wb");//opne in binery write mode
//read the headers to souirce file
fread(&source_info, (sizeof(long)*3 + sizeof(short)),1,fp);

//calucate the number of pix to read
S=source_info.Width*source_info.Height;
source_info.pixels =  (struct Pix *) malloc(sizeof(struct Pix)*S);

//read pixcels
for(i=1;i<=S;i++)
{
//read pixcel form source file
fread(&source_pix,sizeof(struct Pix),1,fp);
source_info.pixels[i-1] = source_pix;
}

// write header to dest file
fwrite(&source_info,  (sizeof(long)*3 + sizeof(short)),1,Dfp);
// write pixels to dest file
for(i=1;i<=S;i++)
{
    fwrite(&source_info.pixels[i-1],sizeof(struct Pix),1,Dfp);
}

//close all fiels
fclose(fp);
fclose(Dfp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't read/write binary files using `FILE*`, rather use read/write system-calls.

Comment: @BrianBrown extended my answer.

Comment: For reference on the various possibilities info can be stored in a so called bmp file: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: The struct `BitMap` you posted will only do for systems with the size of a `long` being 32 bits.

Answer (score 3):

The number of pixels you read (S) is 3762821376 for a sample image i tried. That is obviously far too large.

Have a look at the BMP-spec whether the `struct BitMap` you are using is correct.

**EDIT 1**:

Change these:

```
fread(&source_info, (sizeof(long)*3 + sizeof(short)),1,fp);
...
fwrite(&source_info,  (sizeof(long)*3 + sizeof(short)),1,Dfp);
```

to

```
fread(&source_info, sizeof(source_info),1,fp);
...
fwrite(&source_info, sizeof(source_info),1,Dfp);
```

It now copies my test .bmp fine.

**EDIT 2:**

I think the color-switching problem on your machine comes because you do `source_info.pixels = ...`. You should use your own pointer `Pix* pixels = malloc...` and in the loops change `source_info.pixels` to `pixels`. Just dont assign your malloc into the source_info struct and it should be fine

Comment: changed it as you wrote but now different problem came out. It copies a bmp image but changes it colors also :/ check out the code for this example image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/208/39057820.png/

Comment: strange because mine does, take a look: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/266/ouuut.png/ its my output image, out.bmp

Comment: I think the color-switching problem on your machine comes because you do `source_info.pixels = ...`. You should use your own pointer `Pix* pixels = malloc...` and in the loops change `source_info.pixels` to `pixels`. Just **dont** assign your malloc into the source_info struct and it should be fine.

Comment: it helped, thanks! but unfortunately I NEED to have in one struct, BitMap. How to make it?

Comment: You can always wrap another struct around it: `typedef struct { BitMap header; void* pixels; } HeaderAndPixels;` . By the way: Your bitmap header struct is not complete! It misses some fields see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing to the `source_info.Width` and `source_info.Height` data that's not inited because when you `fread` the header data of the file, you just stop after the first `4 fields`.

Thus the other field of source_info could contain junk data. (expecially `width` and `height` cause they affect the next loops)

Ensure to read the full header changing

```
fread(&source_info, (sizeof(long)*3 + sizeof(short)),1,fp);
```

with

```
fread(&source_info, sizeof(BitMap),1,fp);
```

then ensure to dump it correctly for the same reason, chainging

```
fwrite(&source_info,  (sizeof(long)*3 + sizeof(short)),1,Dfp);
```

with

```
fwrite(&source_info, sizeof(BitMap),1,Dfp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip copying the Pix pointer, it works for me within a single structure as you wanted.

```
fread(&source_info, (sizeof(BitMap) - sizeof(struct Pix*)),1,fp);
```

By the way, the code produces smaller file sizes if you defined the Pix as

```
typedef struct Pix
{
  unsigned char R;
  unsigned char G;
  unsigned char B;
}Pix;
```